# Twitter API: Multiple authenticated users return same home timeline

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I want to display the tweets that users see in their Twitter home timeline. Concept here is

- First, let the user login with "login with Twitter" functionality and get an OAuth token.
- Then request Twitter API with those keys and get tweets.

So far I have achieved to get the timeline of my own developer account.

Here is the Nodejs code to get those tweets.

```
 const {access_token, access_token_secret} = request.body;
 const T = new Twit({
        consumer_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        consumer_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        access_token,
        access_token_secret,
      });
      const tweets = await this.T.get('statuses/home_timeline', { count: 40 });
```

Here is the API request from the frontend

```
export const loadPersonalTweets = (
  access_token,
  access_token_secret
) => () => {
  axios
    .post(`http://localhost:8000/tweet/homeTimeline`, {
      access_token,
      access_token_secret,
    })
    .then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res) // supposed to get user's personal timeline
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
};
```

I have retrieved `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` from my developer account and I receive `access_token` and `access_token_secret` from the frontend app after the user authorizes it.

But it doesn't return what the other user sees in their timeline rather it returns the timeline of my developer account.

Can anyone redirect me to the correct way?
Edit: This is the token I get after users authorize the frontend app
[image]

Comment: When the users sign in, do you store the access token and access token secret from their logins? That's what you need to get the home timeline for their accounts.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question and attached the response after twitter authentication is completed. I save those tokens in the frontend. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?